# How do I enable page compression for Jboss EAP6.2

Tags: http-compression, jboss-eap-6

How can I enable page/gzip compression for JBoss EAP 6.2?

I have found information online for older JBoss AS, but nothing for EAP.

Comment: EAP 6 is built off JBoss AS 7 so it should work the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this by:

file : standalone.xml  (JBoss AS 7+ )

Position : right after

```
<extensions>

</extensions>

<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION" value="on"/>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIME_TYPES" value="text/javascript,text/css,text/html,text/xml,text/json"/>  <!-- add other content types you want to gzip -->
</system-properties>
```